# C++ method to return a dynamic pointer array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-management

I have a class with an array of pointers, which dynamically allocates memory on the constructor at first.
I want to make a method to return this array, because it's a private field.
How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C++ method to return a dynamic pointer array is:

```
std::vector<Mytype*> ret;
//...
return ret;
```

If you have a private pointer array you can return a vector copy oft it if that is what you want:

```
std::vector<Mytype*> ret(MyPrivateArray,MyPrivateArray+PrivateArraySize);
return ret;
```

Comment: @Davidbrcz I don't know either, but that is what he asked for.